# How to backup local git changes for domain users?

Tags: windows, git, windows-server-2008-r2

In our company (A windows domain network), our developers use GIT as their Version Control software.

The main repository (if you can call it that) is backed up daily (fetch + clone - from the backup server)

I want to keep my user's GIT local folders (before they commit) backed up daily.

I was thinking I can get the last changes from the last fetch/commit and only save/backup the files that have changed.

Is it possible?
How can I do it for the entire org?  (I want an automated script that will be launched daily)

I want to avoid a situation, where a developer worked several days (can't commit work) - and loose his work due to disaster.

- Can I track changed files?  (date stamps maybe?)

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your edit.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fetch/clone untracked data from an upstream repo (see "[Pushing untracked content with git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396507/6309)")
That means you cannot initiate that backup process centrally.

You could distribute a script to the users which would rsync or scp their repos to a shared central path.
The other solution would be to use `git archive` or `git bundle`, but the user would add to stash his/her work in progress (which could include untracked files, but the restore would be able to distinguish between staged and untracked changes on `git stash pop`).

> I want to avoid a situation, where a developer worked several days (can't commit work)

If you want to fetch/clone the user repo, then they *must* commit regularly.
Don't forget this isn't SVN: a developer can creates his/her own `dev` branch and commit in it even if the code doesn't compile/don't pass the test. In that aspect, `dev` is a private branch, used only to record daily progress by the developer.
Only public branches (the ones he/she wants to push) should contain only "clean" commits.

Comment: +1 for `rsync`. `git` is awesome, but is a DVCS, not a backup tool.