# Squash history but keep X most recent commits

Tags: git

I'm attempting to remove a large portion of our history in a remote branch, we need to keep the most recent history of ~20-50 commits.

The branch in question has >3500 commits, I have attempted the suggestions from [how-to-delete-all-git-commits-except-the-last-five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929766/how-to-delete-all-git-commits-except-the-last-five/11931881) but I always end up with conflicts..

There's almost exclusively merge commits in the branch, is there a way to squash the first ~3500 commits and keep the most recent history only that doesn't cause conflicts with merges?

Comment: are there merge commits in the last "~20-50 commits" you mention ?

Comment: There are, almost every commit is a merge via PR